# Vagrant Error: The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. (Macbook pro M1)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant for the first time and when I run the command vagrant up --no-provision it runs for a few second and then it gives me this error

`The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the 'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured properly and try again.`

I'm not sure what I should do because I have never used Vagrant before also I'm using an M1 Macbook pro

any help would be great thanks

Comment: You could try adding `vb.gui = true` to your Vagrantfile.  You can also get more debug output from vagrant by prepending any vagrant command with `VAGRANT_LOG=debug`.  That might help you see what might be going wrong.